# Multiple outcome values for simple neural network. What activate function to use

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Hi I'm trying to build a simple neural network with tensorflow, where I give the model the *training_data*, which contains the standard values and i give it the target_data, which is the result I want it to have if the predicted value is near one of those numbers.
For example, if I give the *y_test* a value of 3.5, the model would predict and give a number close to 4. So the condition would say it was a lightsmoker. I searched a bit for activation functions and I learned I can't use sigmoid for what I want to do. I'm quite new on this matter. What i've done so far it's by error and trial.

```
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


training_data=[]
for i in range(0,5):
    training_data.append([random.uniform(0,0.2944)])
for i in range(0,5):
    training_data.append([random.uniform(0.2944,1.7394)])
for i in range(0,5):
    training_data.append([random.uniform(1.7394,3.2394)])
for i in range(0,5):
    training_data.append([random.uniform(3.2394,6)])

target_data=[]
for i in range(0,5):
    target_data.append([1])
for i in range(0,5):
    target_data.append([2])
for i in range(0,5):
    target_data.append([3])
for i in range(0,5):
    target_data.append([4])

y_test= np.array([100])


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(target_data),input_dim=1,activation='softmax'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='relu'))

model.compile( loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

training_data = np.asarray(training_data)
target_data = np.asarray(target_data)

model.fit(training_data, target_data, epochs=50, verbose=0)

target_pred= model.predict(y_test)

target_pred=float(target_pred)

print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (y_test, target_pred))

if( 0<= target_pred <= 1.5):
    print("\nNon-Smoker")
elif(1.5<= target_pred <2.5):
    print("\nPassive Smoker")
elif(2.5<= target_pred <3.5 ):
    print("Lghtsmoker")
else:
    print("Smoker\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helpful guide to using `activation functions` in the final layer as well as corresponding `losses` for different type of problems.

[image]

In your case, I am assuming you are working with a regression task with arbitrary values (any float value as output, not restricted between `0 to 1` or `-1 to 1`). So, skip the activation function and keep `mse` or `mean_squared_error` as your loss function.

---

EDIT:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,input_shape=(1,),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```

Comment: Instead of having 
```
model.add.(tf.leras.layers.Dense...
```
I should just delete this two lines?

Comment: just delete the last line's `activation='relu'` and change the previous lines `activation='softmax'` to `activation='relu'`, that would be a better activation for the previous layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Now I'm getting this error (TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars) but it should be just a minor issue. Have a good day!

Comment: I think that has to do something with what you are using in the first layer. Try, `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,input_shape=(1,),activation='relu'))` in the first layer and keep the second as it is.

Comment: Once this works, make sure you print `model.summary()` to understand what your architecture is.

Comment: Let me know if that worked for you, and do mark the answer if it helped you as it encourages me to help you in the future :). You can reach out to me directly incase of any future questions on SO!

Comment: It's giving out 20 predictions, i think it's because `len(target_data)`. Putting this value to 1 gives me one prediction only. But the value doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: This should give only 1 prediction. from one output.

Comment: Working like a charm now! Thanks!

Comment: @JoséFreitas, I see you removed your correct answer tag. Did the solution not work for you? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your problem as a regression problem where the result of model.predict is a linear value. For that kind of situation the last layer in your model is a linear layer that does not have an activation function. For this kind of problem your loss as mse is fine. Now you could elect to define your problem as a classification problem. Where you have 3 classes, Non-Smoker, Passive-Smoker and Light smoker. Now in that case, your target data in training is not a number in the numerical sense but an integer that indicates which class the training sample represents. For example you could have Non_Smoker with the label 0, Passive_Smoker with the label 1 and Light_Smoker with the label 2. Now the last layer in your model would use a softmax activation function. In model.compile your loss would be sparse_categorical_crossentropy because your labels are integers. If you  one-hot encode your labels, for example Non_Smoker coded as 100, Light_Smoker as 010 and Passive_Smoker coded as 001 then your loss fuction would be categorical_cross_entropy. Now when you ran model.predict on  a test sample it will produce a list containing 3 probabilities. The first in the list is the probability for class 0 - Non_Smoker, second is the probability for class 1 Light Smoker and the third is the probability of the third class Passive_Smoker. Now what you do is use np.argmax to find which index has the highest probability value and that is then the model's prediction.

Comment: While you have some good suggestions, the `smoking_score` that OP is trying to predict is continuous and later interpreted as broad categories. I thought about turning this into a classification problem as well but that would defeat the purpose of predicting a continous score. I was also thinking in lines of `ordinal regression`.